# error while decoding image captured with camera

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, decoding

I am launching the camera to capture a picture, which is stored in a new file in a specific folder, in the external storage.

The problem is that when I try to decode the image from the file using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` in my `onActivityResult()` method, the returned image is `null`. Is this because the file is not yet complete (i.e. the process of the camera has not finished to save the image)? How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code with which I am launching the camera:

```
private void launchCamera() {
    //create folder
    File imagesFolder = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Consts.MEDIA_EXTERNAL_FOLDER);
    if(!imagesFolder.exists())
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    String fileName = "pic_"+Consts.CAMERA_DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date());
    File image = null;
    try {
        image = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".jpg", imagesFolder);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating new file.");
    }
    capturedImageURI = Uri.parse(image.getAbsolutePath());

    //launch camera
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_ACTION);
}
```

And this is when I get the image in the `onActivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_ACTION:
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(capturedImageURI, null);
            File f = new File(capturedImageURI.toString());

            decodedBitmap = Helper.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(filePath);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedBitmap);

            break;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem?

`File`, AFAIK, does not understand `file:///` URL formats, which is what you will get from `capturedImageURI.toString()`. Rather than regenerating the `File`, use the one you already created.

Comment: Thank you so much. At first I was thinking "that's not true, that's not the uri format", and I was right, in fact the output of uri.toString() is the same as file.getAbsolutePath(), but I gave this a try and for some reason this is working. The only thing now is that I can't see the new pic in my folder in the gallery, which means that getContentResolver().notifyChange(capturedImageURI, null) is not working :\

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro: Use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to let the `MediaStore` know to index your picture. I would expect the camera app to do that, but there are *lots* of camera apps, and some perhaps do not when invoked from a third-party app. Also, there may well be a delay in getting the file indexed, let alone in getting your `ContentObserver` notified, just with other work being done on the device.

Comment: I was not aware of MediaScannerConnection, thank you again for your help.